# a confusion on the word "argue"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have 2 meanings I confused with.

> **A.** If one person argues with another, they speak angrily to each other
>   about something that they disagree about. You can also say that two
>   people argue.
>
> Example: They were still arguing.
>
> **B.** If you argue with someone about something, you discuss it with them,
>   with each of you giving your different opinions.
>
> Example: They are arguing over foreign policy

What confused me is whether the meaning of B suggests they are discussing **in an angry way**?

In other words if they are discussing in a moderate way over foreign policy.
Can I say **They are arguing over foreign policy**

Comment: You could say: *"They are having a disagreement over the foreign policy"*

Comment: Like *aloud*, which could mean either *audibly* or *loudly*, *arguing* can be either reasonably or angrily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definition **B** is more technically correct

Argue means:

> to present reasons for or against a thing

Anger is not necessary in order for people to "argue".

The reason why anger and arguing, are associated likely has to do with the fact that it's common for people to get angry with one-another while they argue.

For more, see the definition of "Argue" at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/argue?s=t

Comment: A very clear answer!